# For filtering using data-attributes, In JS how do I match 2 arrays that have the same words but in a different order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to create a filter system that uses data-attributes, I can get it to work if the items selected match the order of the elements data-attributes eg: items selected {fun, easy, cheap} and the elements attributes are in the same order but if I click {easy, cheap, fun} then I don't have any results returned.
Any help on solving this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var filterBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.request-btn'),
  slider = document.querySelector('.slider'),
  cardContainers = $('.cards-container'),
  selectedFilters = [];

filterBtns.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('clicked');
    if (this.classList.contains('clicked')) {
      selectedFilters.push(this.dataset.filter);
    } else {
      selectedFilters.splice(selectedFilters.indexOf(this.dataset.filter), 1);
    }
    updateCards();
  });
});

slider.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value === '0') {
    selectedFilters.push('easy');
  } else if (this.value === '1') {
    selectedFilters.splice(selectedFilters.indexOf('easy', 'diy'), 1);
  } else {
    selectedFilters.push('diy');
  }

  updateCards();
});

var updateCards = function() {
  cardContainers.removeClass('show').filter(function() {
    var data = this.dataset;
    var selectedFiltersValues = selectedFilters.join(' ');
    return selectedFilters.length ? data.filter.includes(selectedFiltersValues) : true;
  }).addClass('show');
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid coral;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.cards-container {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.request-btn.clicked {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-container">
  <div class="left-filter">
    <p>EASY<input type="range" class="slider provider-complexity" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="1">DIY</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-filter">
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="cheap">Cheap</button>
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="fun">fun</button>
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="green">green</button>
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="big">big</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="green">
  <div class="card">1 the tag is - green</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="fun">
  <div class="card">2 the tag is - fun</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="cheap">
  <div class="card">3 the tag is - cheap</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="big">
  <div class="card">4 the tag is - big</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="cheap big">
  <div class="card">5 the tags are - cheap big</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="fun easy cheap">
  <div class="card">6 the tags are - fun easy cheap</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="diy">
  <div class="card">7 the tag is - diy</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="easy">
  <div class="card">8 hthe tag is - easy</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="easy green">
  <div class="card">9 the tags are - easy green</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update based on comment**

Based on the comment, the requirement is that each item must contain all of the filters. If "cheap" and "big" are selected, only items that have "cheap" *and* "big" can be returned.

The change:

```js
    // Get the individual item filters as an array
    var itemData = data.filter.split(' ')
    return selectedFilters.length
    // match on every
    ? selectedFilters.every(function (val) {
        return itemData.indexOf(val) > -1;
      })
    : true;
```

```js
var filterBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.request-btn'),
  slider = document.querySelector('.slider'),
  cardContainers = $('.cards-container'),
  selectedFilters = [];

filterBtns.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('clicked');
    if (this.classList.contains('clicked')) {
      selectedFilters.push(this.dataset.filter);
    } else {
      selectedFilters.splice(selectedFilters.indexOf(this.dataset.filter), 1);
    }
    updateCards();
  });
});

slider.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value === '0') {
    selectedFilters.push('easy');
  } else if (this.value === '1') {
    selectedFilters.splice(selectedFilters.indexOf('easy', 'diy'), 1);
  } else {
    selectedFilters.push('diy');
  }

  updateCards();
});

var updateCards = function() {
  cardContainers.removeClass('show').filter(function() {
    var itemData = data.filter.split(' ')
    return selectedFilters.length
      ? selectedFilters.every(function (val) {
          return itemData.indexOf(val) > -1;
        })
      : true;
  }).addClass('show');
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid coral;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.cards-container {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.request-btn.clicked {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-container">
  <div class="left-filter">
    <p>EASY<input type="range" class="slider provider-complexity" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="1">DIY</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-filter">
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="cheap">Cheap</button>
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="fun">fun</button>
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="green">green</button>
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="big">big</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="green">
  <div class="card">1 the tag is - green</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="fun">
  <div class="card">2 the tag is - fun</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="cheap">
  <div class="card">3 the tag is - cheap</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="big">
  <div class="card">4 the tag is - big</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="cheap big">
  <div class="card">5 the tags are - cheap big</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="fun easy cheap">
  <div class="card">6 the tags are - fun easy cheap</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="diy">
  <div class="card">7 the tag is - diy</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="easy">
  <div class="card">8 hthe tag is - easy</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="easy green">
  <div class="card">9 the tags are - easy green</div>
</div>
```

**Original**

You problem is that you've joined your selected filters, in your `updateCards` function you're then checking if the items `data-filter` includes `cheap fun green`.

The solution is to check if the array of `selectedFilters` includes the elements attribute(s).

**The change**

```js
  const itemData = data.filter.split(' ')
    return selectedFilters.length
    ? selectedFilters.every(function (val) {
        return itemData.indexOf(val) > -1;
      })
    : true;
```

I've updated your example below.
A note on the usage of `.some` It works across all major browsers, if you need to support i.e 6-8 for some hellish reason, you will need a polyfill. [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_some)

```js
var filterBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.request-btn'),
  slider = document.querySelector('.slider'),
  cardContainers = $('.cards-container'),
  selectedFilters = [];

filterBtns.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('clicked');
    if (this.classList.contains('clicked')) {
      selectedFilters.push(this.dataset.filter);
    } else {
      selectedFilters.splice(selectedFilters.indexOf(this.dataset.filter), 1);
    }
    updateCards();
  });
});

slider.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value === '0') {
    selectedFilters.push('easy');
  } else if (this.value === '1') {
    selectedFilters.splice(selectedFilters.indexOf('easy', 'diy'), 1);
  } else {
    selectedFilters.push('diy');
  }

  updateCards();
});

var updateCards = function() {
  cardContainers.removeClass('show').filter(function() {
    var data = this.dataset;
    return selectedFilters.length
    ? selectedFilters.some(function (val) {
        return data.filter.includes(val);
      })
    : true;
  }).addClass('show');
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid coral;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.cards-container {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.request-btn.clicked {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-container">
  <div class="left-filter">
    <p>EASY<input type="range" class="slider provider-complexity" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="1">DIY</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-filter">
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="cheap">Cheap</button>
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="fun">fun</button>
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="green">green</button>
    <button class="request-btn" data-filter="big">big</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="green">
  <div class="card">1 the tag is - green</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="fun">
  <div class="card">2 the tag is - fun</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="cheap">
  <div class="card">3 the tag is - cheap</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="big">
  <div class="card">4 the tag is - big</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="cheap big">
  <div class="card">5 the tags are - cheap big</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="fun easy cheap">
  <div class="card">6 the tags are - fun easy cheap</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="diy">
  <div class="card">7 the tag is - diy</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="easy">
  <div class="card">8 hthe tag is - easy</div>
</div>
<div class="cards-container show" data-filter="easy green">
  <div class="card">9 the tags are - easy green</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The above solution works well for showing all elements that match the selected buttons but how do you only show elements that match exactly the selected buttons?
eg: I choose Cheap and Big, only show elements that have Cheap and Big in their array of attributes, then hide all others. So an element with only the attribute Cheap would be hidden.

Comment: @Nathan Answer updated to reflect these requirements. The change was to split each filter item to create an array and then use `Array.prototype.every` to only get items that match all of the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isArrayEqual(a, b) {
    var arrA = a.join() // Array as String
    var arrB = b.join() // Array as String
    
    // Compare length of two string
    if (arrA.length != arrB.length) {
        return false
    }
    
    var totalA = 0
    var totalB = 0
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arrA.length; i++) {
        totalA += arrA.charCodeAt(i)
        totalB += arrB.charCodeAt(i)
    }
    
    // Array is same, if both total equal
    if (totalA == totalB) {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that looks at the values of each array and then only shows cards that have that combination of values in it's data-attribute.
The problen with the original question, it only showed cards that had values in the same order, the first soultion showed any card that matched a value, not combination of values.

```
var checker = function(arr, target) {
    return target.every(function(v){
        return arr.includes(v);
    });
}

return checker(dataArray, selectedFilters);
```